# How to import a store into another store in React using mobx

Tags: reactjs, mobx

[image]

Still somewhat new to React and I am working on a project where it turns out I need one store to communicate with another store. In the past, I have had a store that stored data that would allow the different parts of the project to communicate however this structure is a bit different. Is there a way to import the ProcessDatasetsStore into the IndividualModeStore? Can I just simply import one store into the other with the import statement?

My IndiviudalModeStore is setup like this

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import { observable, computed, action } from "mobx";
import {boundMethod} from "autobind-decorator";

/**
 * The store for the edit in individual mode page in process datasets
 */

class IndividualModeStore {
    constructor(rootStore) {
        this.rootStore = rootStore;
    }...
```

and my ProcessDatasetsStore is setup like this

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { observable, computed, action } from "mobx";
import {boundMethod} from "autobind-decorator";



export const panelTypes = {
    metadata: "metadata",
    table1: "table1"
};

class ProcessDatasetsStore {
    constructor(rootStore) {
        this.rootStore = rootStore;
    }...
```

Comment: Can you make some simple example on https://codesandbox.io/? Just root store, and couple others store, maybe a component. Would be easier to see how you use them, because right now it is not clear are your stores singletones, how you assign them in the root store and etc.

Comment: Oh sure, will add that here. Thanks!